# get Array of integers from a list of object members

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
$arr = @()
for($i=0;$i -lt 100; $i++) {
  $obj = New-Object myType
  $obj.intMember = $i
  $arr += $obj
}
```

And I want to turn this into an array of integers.  My approach would be:

```
$intArr = Select-Object intMember
```

But this doesn't seem to be doing what I want.  How do I get an actual integer array from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
$intArr = Select-Object -ExpandProperty intMember
```